# Creating a Color Key?

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

How can I create a colour key in LaTeX to show what the colours of this table mean?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you specify what the key is supposed to look like and where you’re struggling, specifically? You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Could we have the code for this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}       
\node [label=label1,draw,fill=red] (node1) {};
\node [label={[name=l] label2},draw,fill=yellow] (node2) at ([xshift=2cm]node1.east){};  
\node [label={[name=l] label3},draw,fill=blue] (node3) at ([xshift=2cm]node2.east){};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]